# Angular2 revert table row's color back to original after deletion

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Using Angular2, I have a striped table on my main page that when you click a row it changes color and when clicked again, goes back to the original color. When a row is currently clicked you can delete it. My problem is that when I delete a row that isn't the last row, after that row is deleted the row that was after it has the changed color.

For example, if I click and delete row 2, after deletion of row 2, row 3 is highlighted with the changed color. What I want is for no row to be highlighted after a deletion. Keep in mind that row 3 simply is being shown as clicked by having the highlighted color but in the code no row is programmatically represented as highlighted.

HTML from my main page where the table is (`#015939`green is my highlight color, even rows are `white` by default, odd rows are `#d3d3d3` grey by default) followed by the tag for the delete button child component with selector `deletebutton`:

**`mainpage.component.html`**

```
<tr *ngFor="let dPoint of theData; let idx=index; let even=even" (click)="onClick(dPoint, idx)" (row)="received($event)"
      [style.backgroundColor]="clickedRow == idx ? '#015939' : (even ? 'white' : '#d3d3d3')" [style.color]="clickedRow == idx ? 'white' : '#015939'">
    <td>{{dPoint.tDataPoint}}</td>
    <td>{{dPoint.tICCP}}</td>
    <td>{{dPoint.tStartDate}}</td>
    <td>{{dPoint.tEndDate}}</td>
</tr> 

<deletebutton [receivedRow]='toSend'></deletebutton>
```

HTML for the button that deletes the row that was clicked

**`deletebutton.component.html`**

```
//this HTML is represented by using deletebutton tag above
<button type="submit" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="delete()" class="btn icon-trash tableButton"></button>
```

Typescript function from my main page that emits the row that was clicked:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main-page',
  styleUrls: ['../app.component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'mainpage.component.html'
})


export class MainPageComponent implements OnInit {

  clickedRow:number;
  toSend:DataTable;
  @Output() row: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>(); 

  onClick(message:DataTable, idx:any){
    let d = message.tDataPoint;
    let i = message.tICCP;
    let s = message.tStartDate;
    let e = message.tEndDate;
    if(this.clickedRow == idx) {
      this.clickedRow = -1;
      this.toSend = null;
    } else {
      this.clickedRow = idx;
      this.toSend = new DataTable(d, i, s, e);
    }
    this.row.emit(this.toSend);
  }
```

Typescript function to delete the clicked row (a child component of my main page):

```
@Component({
 selector: 'deletebutton',
 templateUrl: './deletebutton.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['../app.component.css']
})
export class DeletebuttonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() receivedRow:DataTable;

  delete(){
    var count = 0;
    var length = DPS.length;
    if (this.receivedRow != null) {
      for (let entry in DPS) {
        if (DPS[entry].tDataPoint === this.receivedRow.tDataPoint) {
          DPS.splice(parseInt(entry), 1);
        } else if ((count === (length-1)) && (DPS[entry].tDataPoint !== this.receivedRow.tDataPoint)) {
            alert("Please select a row first");
        } else if (count !== length) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Table before anything is clicked or deleted:
[image]

Table After row 2 is selected:
[image]

Table after row 2 is deleted:
[image]

I need the table to only be white and grey rows after deleting a row. Notice how in the 3rd screenshot, the new row 2 (which used to be row 3) is highlighted

I've tried working with `@Input` and `@Output` to somehow send the row that will be highlighted after deletion of the previous row to change `this.clickedRow` but can't seem to nail down the logic.

Comment: Please show more of your templates.. where those two `onClick` functions are triggered..

Comment: Added the `button` that triggers the second `onClick` method to delete the row clicked. The HTML for the first `onClick` method is already in the first set of HTML. Also included HTML for `deletebutton` that takes the row that was clicked on as input

Comment: I don't get how you select and how you delete a row. You just need to set the `clickedRow` to `-1` if the deleted row is the same as `clickedRow`.

Comment: each `tr` tag has `(click)="onClick(dPoint, idx)" (row)="received($event)` to get the row that was clicked and emit it using `@Output`. The `deletebutton` uses `[receivedRow]='toSend'` to get the clicked row as input. This `deletebutton` is a button which calls the second `onClick` method using `(click)="onClick()"`. Problem is that after deleted I'm having trouble setting `clickedRow` back to `-1` from the `button`'s `onClick` function.

Comment: Plunker isn't working.. wanted to show you a better way.. will try later again :)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer basically the issue is the first `onClick` function gets called once when a row is clicked. The row then changes color and the row is deleted. When deleting, `this.clickedRow` remains at the same index. I understand why it's remaining that, I just don't know how to access `this.clickedRow` from the delete button's `onClick` function to change it. Tried creating instance of the component that has `clickedRow` property but keep getting undefined errors.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you try to accomplish.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I don't want any row to be highlighted or represented as being currently clicked after deleting a row. When I delete a row, the row that comes after it is highlighted. I'm adding screenshots so show this

Comment: Why do you use the same method `onClick()` for highlighting and deleting?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sorry for the confusion with that. The **first** `onClick` method is in my component for the main page. The **second** `onClick` is in my component for deletion. They are separate existing functions in separate Typescript. I understand how that is confusing I apologize

Comment: So the delete button and the `<tr ...` are not in the same component?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer no they are not. My main page has the `deletebutton` tag which is it's own component. The HTML for that component is the `button` tag. I changed the name of the `button`'s click function to make that logic more clear

Comment: Then my answer should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128725/discussion-between-drew13-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to use `deletebutton` in `mainpage.component.html`. Just replace it with the HTML for the `button`.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="delete()" class="btn icon-trash tableButton"></button>
```

Then move your `delete` function from `deletebutton` Typescript to your `mainpage` Typescript and add the line `this.clickedRow = -1;` and change `receivedRow` to `toSend` like this

```
delete(){
  var count = 0;
  var length = DPS.length;
  if (this.toSend != null) {
    for (let entry in DPS) {
      if (DPS[entry].tDataPoint === this.toSend.tDataPoint) {
        DPS.splice(parseInt(entry), 1);
        this.clickedRow = -1;
        this.deleted = true;
      } else if ((count === (length-1)) && (DPS[entry].tDataPoint !== this.toSend.tDataPoint)) {
        alert("Please select a row first");
      } else if (count !== length) {
        count = count + 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way, after selecting a row and clicking the `button`, the `delete` function gets called from the same Typescript instead of having to work between two separate components.